# How to rename every ListTile differently in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list title that I want to have 100 tiles I want to have a separate name for every tile. I want to know how can I implement Named arrays from `ListView.builder` to the `Tiles`.

My code is something like this:

Code:

```
final items = List<String>.generate(114, (i) => "index $i");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chapters Index'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: If you want named every title differently ,just add different data in item list

Comment: Mofidul Islam answer the question seperately

Comment: Where is item list?

Comment: final items = List<String>.generate(114, (i) => "index $i");
this one

Comment: lets first understand the problem then will answer

Comment: okay how is that working?

Comment: you are already making every list item seperate with index specified.

Comment: List<Item>items=[Item(name:"name1"),tem(name:"name2"),tem(name:"name2")]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237996/discussion-between-mike-osborn-and-mofidul-islam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare list like this

```
List<Item>items=[Item(name:"name1"),tem(name:"name2"),tem(name:"name2")];
```

Use it like this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chapters Index'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index].name),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Your Item modal

```
class Item{
String? name;
Item({required this.name};
}
```

Comment: plz explain a litttle

Comment: i gotta go sry but thaks for the anser you can still explain it t me

Comment: but i gotta go sry

Comment: sure will do   ..its okay

Comment: i tried it but it isnt working

Comment: i want to know if i have to create the class in same page or another page?

Comment: you can create in same page or different it will work

Comment: can u show me how it works?

Comment: can u edit your answer and show it with my code

Comment: plz add the full code with my answer I am still not getting it

Answer (score 0):

I got a little help from flutter site from here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list